# Bibliography entry with two couting entries

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I have one style with two counter for each item in reference section. E.G:

[image: two entries]

In the `.cls` file we have:

```
% Configurações de bibliografia
\newcounter{iteminbib}
\addtocounter{iteminbib}{0}
\newlength{\bibmargin}
\setlength{\bibmargin}{20pt}
\TabPositions{\bibmargin}
\newcommand{\quotes}[1]{``#1''}
\newcommand{\insertbibliography}[1]{%
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\bibsep}{4pt}
\setlength\itemindent{0pt}
\setlength{\bibhang}{\bibmargin}
{\setstretch{0.85}
\fontsize{8}{10} \selectfont
  \bibliographystyle{eamc-classFiles/eamc-ref.bib}
  \renewcommand\refname{REFERENCES}  
\bibliography{#1}}
```

Where I change to have only one counter?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The presentation of the bibliography in your document depends on many things, it is next to impossible to investigate an issue like this if we don't know about the document class you use, about the bibliography/citation packages you load, which bibliography style you use (that is shown in the code snippet) and what your `.bib` entries look like. Ideally you would show us that in a short compilable example document that only contains the relevant bits of code from your large document but is still fully compilable (often such a document s called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/)

Comment: You probably want to fix the spelling of "couting" in the question; I *think* it should be "counting".